# Найти все неизвестные одинаковые строки и заменить?

Tags: c#

1) Имеется txt файл, в котором есть повторяющиеся слова, но мы не знаем какие это слова. Т.е поиск по конкретному слову не подходит,но может регуляркой если только ?
И нужно заменить эти неизвестные повторяющиеся слова на рандомно-сгенерированноые слова из символов которые находятся в массиве. При этом у одинаковых слов долно быть одно и тоже рандомно-сгенерированное слово.
Например:

```
UnknownWord1
UnknownWord2
UnknownWord3
UnknownWord1
UnknownWord2
UnknownWord3
```

После замены на рандомно-сгенерированные слова должно получится что-то вроде этого:

```
ABCDE
ACDBE
EBCDA
ABCDE
ACDBE
EBCDA
```

Собственно вопрос:
1. Как мне найти эти неизвестные слова и при этом заменить их на рандомно-сгенерированные слова?

Comment: А если слово только раз встречается?

Comment: `повторяющиеся слова, но мы не знаем какие это слова` `нужно заменить эти неизвестные повторяющиеся слова` `UnknownWord1`
`UnknownWord2` Так они у вас неизвестные или по определенному формату как в примере: `UnknownWord**` ?

Comment: заведи словарь, если слово уже есть - заменяй его на уже содержащееся значение, если нет - генерируйрандомное слово и помещай в словарь

Comment: @ГеннадийП слова неизвестны, их надо найти в тексте.

Comment: Советую вам почитать об регулярных выражениях. Они помогут вам задать необходимый шаблон для поиска строк.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как вариант с LINQ...

**Исходный текст**:

> UnknownWord1
>   UnknownWord2
>   UnknownWord3
>   UnknownWord1
>   UnknownWord2
>   UnknownWord3
>   Hello World!

**Генерация случайного слова** ([источник](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1344242/6808809)):

```
private static Random random = new Random();
public static string RandomString(int length = 5)
{
    const string chars = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
    return new string(Enumerable.Repeat(chars, length)
        .Select(s => s[random.Next(s.Length)]).ToArray());
}
```

**Составляем словарь из случайных слов:**
Тут мы группируем все слова, далее с помощью `Where` отсекаем без повторов, ну и затем формируем `Dictionary`, ключом которого будет слово, значением - сгенерированный текст.

```
var randoms = lines.GroupBy(x => x).Where(x => x.Count() > 1).ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => RandomString());
```

**Формируем результат:**
Тут просто с помощью `Select` задаем каждому слову новое значение, которое берем из ранее созданного словаря. Если значение пустое, то берем оригинал.

```
var result = lines.Select(x => randoms.FirstOrDefault(f => f.Key == x).Value ?? x);
```

**Результат:**

> RDJKD
>   YUGLR
>   MQKRZ
>   RDJKD
>   YUGLR
>   MQKRZ
>   Hello World!

Comment: Но он ищет только слова в линии, а если слово будет в тексте то он просто не увидит его.

Comment: @Gigabait Этот вариант работает с массивом. Что будет в массиве - это уже совершенно другой вопрос. Вот допустим пару [примеров](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4970538/how-to-get-all-words-of-a-string-in-c) получения всех слов в тексте, что в результате даст тот самый массив, по которому будет работать данный код. P.S. Вы изначально не указали, что слова могут быть в тексте, вы дали четкий вариант того, как выглядят исходные данные. Менять так кардинально вопрос очень плохо!!

Answer (score 0):

Создать словарь (dictionary, map) `string-string`
Выделить очередное слово.
Если оно (как ключ) есть в словаре, заменить его на значение для данного ключа
Иначе назначить ему замену, вывести её в результат и записать пару (слово;замена) в словарь

(как назначается замена - определите сами)

Вот пример полного рабочего кода на Python, на шарпе будет по сути похоже:

```
import random
chars = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWZYZ'
lst = ['Word1', 'Word2','Word3','Word1','Word2']
map = {}
strset = set()
result = []
for line in lst:
    if line in map:
        result.append(map[line])
    else:
        rstr = ''.join([chars[random.randrange(26)] for _ in range(5)])
        while rstr in strset:
            rstr = ''.join([chars[random.randrange(26)] for _ in range(5)])
        map[line] = rstr
        strset.add(rstr)
        result.append(rstr)

print(result)

['SQMHZ', 'VBEZB', 'YNTDZ', 'SQMHZ', 'VBEZB']
```

Comment: Стоп, я не могу вести словать потому что названия функций разные. Вы думаете все люди дают одинаковые названия функциям ? 
Я ведь правильно понял ? Вы хотите чтоб я добавил словарь и проверять каждое слово на совпадение из словаря и заменять его ?

Comment: Об этом я не мог думать, поскольку о функциях и людях могли знать только Вы. Словарь создаётся по ходу чтения, его ключи - ваши слова типа `UnknownWord1`